# Replace column based on column names

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have 65 columns, but a sample of data could be as follows:

```
 df<-read.table (text="  Name   D   A   D   E
    Rose    D   D   C   B
    Smith   B   A   D   D
    Lora    A   A   D   D
    Javid   A   D   D   B
    Ahmed   C   A   E   A
    Helen   B   A   D   D
    Nadia   A   A   D   A

", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table:

```
Name    D   A   D   E
Rose    2   1   1   1
Smith   1   2   2   1
Lora    1   2   2   1
Javid   1   1   2   1
Ahmed   1   2   1   1
Helen   1   2   2   1
Nadia   1   2   2   1
```

The numbers follow the first raw. For example, the second column is D, so all Ds should read 2 and else should read 1. Or in the third column, which is A, all As should read 2 and else should read 1 and so on. Please consider I have 65 columns.  I understand I should have different names for the columns, but In this case, I cannot change them as you understand it.

Comment: I am trying understand what you are trying to do and it is a bit unclear, can you elaborate?

Comment: Never use the same column name twice.

Comment: How can you have the same name twice?

Comment: You should add `check.names = FALSE` into `read.table()`; otherwise the second `D` will be renamed as `D.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ifelse` and `sapply`:

```r
df[2:ncol(df)] <- sapply(2:ncol(df), function(i) ifelse(df[i] == colnames(df[i]), 2, 1))
```

output

```r
#> df
   Name D A D E
1  Rose 2 1 1 1
2 Smith 1 2 2 1
3  Lora 1 2 2 1
4 Javid 1 1 2 1
5 Ahmed 1 2 1 1
6 Helen 1 2 2 1
7 Nadia 1 2 2 1
```

data

```r
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Rose", "Smith", "Lora", "Javid", "Ahmed", 
"Helen", "Nadia"), D = c("D", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A"), 
    A = c("D", "A", "A", "D", "A", "A", "A"), D = c("C", "D", 
    "D", "D", "E", "D", "D"), E = c("B", "D", "D", "B", "A", 
    "D", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I run it for 65 columns, I get all 1. any thought?

Comment: Maybe you did not call your dataframe `df`? otherwise, I don't see why

Comment: Why I don't get the output provided?

Comment: Maybe your column names and values in the dataframe are all different? or different in class

Comment: Not at all, I  exactly copy-pasted data and your codes

Comment: Oh, I get it; use `function` instead of \. Check edit. \ is a shorthand for `function` since R 4.1.

Comment: Sorry, still does not work, check the output

Comment: I added the data set I'm using (which is yours), try with that. Other than that, if it does not work, then edit your question to make that appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
cols = names(df)[-1]
df[cols] = lapply(cols, \(x) (df[[x]] == x) + 1L)

#    Name D A
# 1  Rose 2 1
# 2 Smith 1 2
# 3  Lora 1 2
# 4 Javid 1 1
# 5 Ahmed 1 2
# 6 Helen 1 2
# 7 Nadia 1 2
```

Simplified data (without repeated column names)

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Rose", "Smith", "Lora", "Javid", "Ahmed", "Helen", "Nadia"),
  D    = c("D", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A"),
  A    = c("D", "A", "A", "D", "A", "A", "A")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, you can `stack`, replace and `unstack`, i.e

```
stack_df <- stack(df[-1])
stack_df$values <- ifelse(stack_df$values == stack_df$ind, 2, 1)
cbind.data.frame(Name = df$Name, unstack(stack_df))

#   Name D A E
#1  Rose 2 1 1
#2 Smith 1 2 1
#3  Lora 1 2 1
#4 Javid 1 1 1
#5 Ahmed 1 2 1
#6 Helen 1 2 1
#7 Nadia 1 2 1
```

**DATA**

```
structure(list(Name = c("Rose", "Smith", "Lora", "Javid", "Ahmed", 
"Helen", "Nadia"), D = c("D", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A"), 
    A = c("D", "A", "A", "D", "A", "A", "A"), E = c("B", "D", 
    "D", "B", "A", "D", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` option with `ifelse` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(D:E, ~ifelse(. == cur_column(), 2, 1)))
#>    Name D A D.1 E
#> 1  Rose 2 1   1 1
#> 2 Smith 1 2   1 1
#> 3  Lora 1 2   1 1
#> 4 Javid 1 1   1 1
#> 5 Ahmed 1 2   1 1
#> 6 Helen 1 2   1 1
#> 7 Nadia 1 2   1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

The data:

```
df <- read.table (
  text = "  Name   A   B   C   D
    Rose    D   D   C   B
    Smith   B   A   D   D
    Lora    A   A   D   D
    Javid   A   D   D   B
    Ahmed   C   A   E   A
    Helen   B   A   D   D
    Nadia   A   A   D   A

",
  header = TRUE
)

> df
   Name A B C D
1  Rose D D C B
2 Smith B A D D
3  Lora A A D D
4 Javid A D D B
5 Ahmed C A E A
6 Helen B A D D
7 Nadia A A D A
```

Note that i changed the column names

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(!c(Name),
                .fns = ~ ifelse(.x == cur_column(), 2, 1)))

   Name A B C D
1  Rose 1 1 2 1
2 Smith 1 1 1 2
3  Lora 2 1 1 2
4 Javid 2 1 1 1
5 Ahmed 1 1 1 1
6 Helen 1 1 1 2
7 Nadia 2 1 1 1
```

The `mutate`-command modifies columns in dataframes. Using the `across()`-function we specify that the mutation should be applied to more than one column. inside the across-call, we select every column but the name column using `!c(Name)`. We then specify a function that compares the name of the column `cur_column()` with the values in the column `.x`. If they are the same, set the value to 2, else to 1.

EDIT: used `ifelse` instead of `case_when` as there is only one condition to check

Comment: I have updated my question about changing the name of the columns.

Comment: you cannot have two identical column names in a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each row with the column names. Adding 1 to the logical values converts `FALSE` and `TRUE` into `1` and `2` respectively.

```r
df[-1] <- t((t(df[-1]) == names(df)[-1]) + 1)
df

#    Name D A D E
# 1  Rose 2 1 1 1
# 2 Smith 1 2 2 1
# 3  Lora 1 2 2 1
# 4 Javid 1 1 2 1
# 5 Ahmed 1 2 1 1
# 6 Helen 1 2 2 1
# 7 Nadia 1 2 2 1
```